# 12 clusters, 12 different icons using Leaflet library for Javascript

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I would like to display points/markers on a map. There are 12 clusters of points and each cluster should have a unique marker/icon.

In this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/szeconku/g1bh6sr1/) I have displayed sample data on two clusters with each its own icon. Currently, there are only 3-4 points in each cluster. The actual data contains 100-200 points in each cluster so clearly the solution is not optimal. I would like to read the 12 clusters more easily. Thought of using a class statement, assigning each class (=cluster) an icon. Not sure how to start.

```
    var map = L.map("map");

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

map.setView([48.87, 2.35], 12);

//STEP 1
var leafIcons = L.Icon.extend({
    options: {
        //shadowUrl: 'leaf-shadow.png',
        iconSize:     [100, 100],
        //shadowSize:   [50, 64],
        iconAnchor:   [22, 94],
        //shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
        popupAnchor:  [-3, -76]
    }
});

//STEP 2
var greenIcon = new leafIcons({iconUrl: 'http://www.marchigiana.org.br/home/images/Diversas/Map-Marker-Marker-Outside-Chartreuse-icon.png'}),
    blueIcon = new leafIcons({iconUrl: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png'});

//STEP 3
L.icon = function (options) {
    return new L.Icon(options);
};


//Green icon cluster
L.marker([48.90, 2.35], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup("I am a green leaf.");
L.marker([48.90, 2.36], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup("I am a green leaf.");
L.marker([48.89, 2.34], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup("I am a green leaf.");

//Blue icon cluster
L.marker([48.84, 2.35], {icon: blueIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup("I am a blue icon");
L.marker([48.85, 2.35], {icon: blueIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup("I am a blue icon");
L.marker([48.84, 2.34], {icon: blueIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup("I am a blue icon");
L.marker([48.83, 2.36], {icon: blueIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup("I am a blue icon");
```

Any ideas on approaches?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed having hundreds of points simultaneously on your map will make it not really readable, as well as considerably slow down visitors' browser.

If I understand correctly, besides the number, you would like to be able to differentiate your different types of icons ("clusters")?

To decrease the number of points displayed simultaneously, you could use some [clustering plugin](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#clusteringdecluttering).

E.g., with [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) you could create 1 `L.markerClusterGroup` per type / cluster of points, so that they cluster only with each other (and not among several types), specifying a custom cluster icon for each group (see how to [customize them](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#customising-the-clustered-markers) / [demo](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-custom.html) / [demo source](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/master/example/marker-clustering-custom.html))

JavaScript:

```js
var mcgGreen = L.markerClusterGroup({
  iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
    return L.divIcon({
      html: cluster.getChildCount(),
      className: 'mycluster',
      iconSize: L.point(40, 40)
    });
  }
}).addTo(map);
var mcgBlue = L.markerClusterGroup({
  iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
    return L.divIcon({
      html: cluster.getChildCount(),
      className: 'mycluster mycluster-blue',
      iconSize: L.point(40, 40)
    });
  }
}).addTo(map);

L.marker([48.90, 2.35], {
  icon: greenIcon
}).addTo(mcgGreen);

L.marker([48.84, 2.35], {
  icon: blueIcon
}).addTo(mcgBlue);
```

CSS:

```css
.mycluster {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.mycluster-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/g1bh6sr1/2/

Comment: May have formulated it wrong (apologies) but what I would like to do is to read data in a more convenient way. Data will only contain coordinates and names. So instead of having to write out. 'L.marker([48.90, 2.35], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup("I am a green leaf.");' for each green point e.g., I would like to create properties for each cluster.

Comment: Sorry I still do not understand what you mean… :-S

Comment: I will be reading points in an array much like GeoJSON's's MultiPoint. Instead of being an actual GeoJSON file, it will be a lot of point coordinated separated by a semicolon.

Comment: Then you can simply loop through your array with JavaScript and build your marker code from there. I am sure you will find plenty resources for that, including here on SO. Good luck!